# Visit url with curl like user

Tags: php, curl

I have a shopping cart and i want a curl function to add the products to the cart, it's added when the user click to the link "Add to cart" but i try many curl function and the cart still empty:

My code:

```
$url = 'The href of the add to cart button when click on it the product added to the cart';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard if you don't provide the actual adress. Maybe you have to save the cookie after you logged in and then use CURLOPT_COOKIE?